# Will unused CTE in a SQL statement be run

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a question about CTEs. You can start of a sql statement by WITH and then you can construct one or multiple CTE queries, which you then in the end can make (in this case) a select on.

My question is: will all CTE queries be executed or only the ones who are being used?

E.g.

```
WITH cte_1
as (
 Select * from table1
),
cte_2
as (
 Select * from table2
)
Select * from cte_1
```

Will this mean that a select will be executed on table1 and table2?

Comment: I would assume the early "rephrasing query phase" would automatically strip it out, but I can be wrong.

Comment: I do not think table2 will be accessed in your query. Only data will be selected form table1 since you are using it in your final/ select

Comment: A quick test.  The execution plan will ignore the 2nd cte

Comment: You could probably construct a query that would fool the optimizer. Most of the time this shouldn't cause of problem though and unnecessary ctes will be disregarded. You also shouldn't think of it as being "executed" as any kind of discrete step in the larger query.

Comment: Everything that the optimizer is able to prove as having no effect will be eliminated. That includes not actually fetching columns from subqueries that are not required later in the chain, and removing left joins whose columns are not required and that do not change the number of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete Master Gordon's answer (I dare) :

if you declare 2 cte, and use none of them, you also get that error message

```
with cte as (select 1/0 as val), cte2 as (select 1/0 as val)
select 1

Msg 422 Level 16 State 4 Line 2 
Common table expression defined but not used.
```

But if you use at least one, the statement is accepted :

```
with cte_divide_by_zero as (select 1/0 as val), cte_legit as (select 'it works' as val)
select * from cte_divide_by_zero 

Msg 8134 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

And if you select the other CTE, it proves that your unused CTE is never executed as no error occurs :

```
with cte_divide_by_zero as (select 1/0 as val), cte_legit as (select 'it works' as val)
select * from cte_legit 

val
--------
it works
```

Comment: It also works if you declare a table variable before the cte, and select from that. I imagine it'll work if you select from any other table too. Cte's are treated just like a subquery, and are joined to the outer query. If there is nothing to join to, it's an obvious error. You can't select from just a subquery

Answer (score 3):

I get this message:

> Msg 422 Level 16 State 4 Line 2
>
> Common table expression defined but not used.

when running:

```
with cte as (select 1/0 as val)
select 1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2f48d387b6a48a1328f1112295538b8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Interesting, it works when main query is `SELECT * FROM tab` or `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` is applied [db<>demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba70a62f620e23bf91625c168477f7d5)

Comment: See my further experiment gordon :)